# How to connect HackRF to Wireshark?

Tags: wireless, wireshark

How to capture ZigBee waves using HackRF and how to analyze it through Wireshark?

Answer (score 1):

Before [RFTap](https://rftap.github.io) was made available recently, you would have to [configure a named pipe from GNURadio pcap](https://sharkfest.wireshark.org/sharkfest.13/presentations/NAP-11_Expanding-Wireshark-Beyond-Ethernet-and-Network-Interfaces_Kershaw-Ryan.pdf) output.

Which protocol(s) are of interest to you for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

When you mean analyze - this creates some confusion.

The Excellent RF-Tap link mentioned by @atdre will feed a tabular data set into Wireshark, so you may see fields like

```
- Mac Address 
- Freq
```

But the "RF Data" - can not be analyzed that way. For this you need to use a product like Gnu-Radio, and in Gnu-Radio specify which demodulation mechanism you will use, and if this produces data i.e. telemetry this could be output into a csv file.